# File cannot be used because another process is using it - can't find open stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using a StreamWriter to write to a file. I'm using a "using" so it should close automatically however when I try to save(which writes to the file) it gives me the "cannot access file because another process is using it" error. I can't seem to figure out where or why it is giving me this error. This is my code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static bool saveToCSV(string[] valueArray)
    {
        bool saveOK = false;

        try
        {
            string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath + "\\spreadsheet.csv", false))
            {

                foreach (var i in valueArray)
                {
                    if (i.ToString() == "\n")
                    {
                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        {
                            if (i.ToString() == "")
                            {
                                sw.Write(" ");
                                sw.Write(",");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sw.Write(i.ToString());
                                sw.Write(",");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                sw.Flush();
            }//close using

            saveOK = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            saveOK = false;
        }

        return saveOK;
    }
```

Comment: Try running [Handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to see which process is blocking the resource.

Comment: The code looks fine except you have one additional set of `{ }` in this line but should not hurt the code ..just had to take a second look real quick..`{
                            if (i.ToString() == "")
                            {
                                sw.Write(" ");
                                sw.Write(",");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sw.Write(i.ToString());
                                sw.Write(",");
                            }
                        }`

Comment: look thru all of your code to see if you are creating another instance of a StreamWriter or StreamReader for that fact..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks OK.

Where else are you handling the file? Are all other file IO operations inclosed in a `using` block? What other applications might be touching the file?

If you open the file elsewhere and haven't disposed of the stream or if another application has the file open you will get this exception.

Comment: Mm. Now that you mentioned it I looked at my "open File" method and I saw that I never closed the stream after reading. I feel so silly now.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably going on here is that your `saveToCSV` method is being called twice at the same time.  Essentially two clients calling into the web service at the same time.  This can lead to a situation where the first call has the file open for writing and hence the second call is denied access.

In order to protect against this you should use a lock to regulate access to the file

```
private static object _key = new object();

[WebMethod]
public static bool saveToCSV(string[] valueArray)
{
   ...
   lock (_key) { 
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath + "\\spreadsheet.csv")) {
      ...
    }
   }
}
```

Now if more than one client call occurs simultaneously they will only try to access the file one at a time

Comment: thank you very much for your input. What actually happened was that in my "openCSV" method I never closed the stream :(. But this is a very interesting read